# Why doesn't git recognize that my file has been changed?

Tags: git, git-commit

here what i did:

i committed few files.
after that i got this status

```
$ git status
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in topGamesMenu.php.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
# On branch TopGamesMenu
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   index.php
#       modified:   nbproject/private/private.xml
#       new file:   topGamesMenu.php
#
```

then i wanted to push

```
git push -m 'logos vom den besten spielen im menu implementiert'
```

but i realized the massage parameter should be at the commit not at push command.
so committed again

```
$ git commit -m 'logo von dem vier besten spielem um menu implementiert'
[TopGamesMenu warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in topGamesMenu.php.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
8fa4dea] logo von dem vier besten spielem um menu implementiert
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in topGamesMenu.php.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
3 files changed, 133 insertions(+), 86 deletions(-)
create mode 100644 topGamesMenu.php
```

after this command my git status shows no more changes.

```
$ git status
# On branch TopGamesMenu
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

---EDIT---

git push doesnt work. git says

```
Everything up-to-date
```

what is wrong?

Comment: Nothing is wrong per se.  You made a new commit simple because the line endings changed in a few files.  By the way, did that `git push` actually work?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. Your first command was `git add` which prepared the staging area for a `git commit` with a message, and now you are ready to `git push`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the push doesnt work. git says "Everything up-to-date". but there is no change in my remote repo.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you are seeing is expected!

`Git` won't list your modified files in `git status` once it is committed. In fact, if you would have set upstream, it should something like

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/<your branch>' by 1 commit.
```

If you want to see the modified files, you use

```
git log --name-only
```

Comment: with git log i found my commit but. how can i push it? 

$ git log
commit 8fa4dea4ad152c68f7c1284357891641d20ba0ea
Author: ***
Date:   Tue Jul 26 02:20:45 2016 +0200

    logo von dem vier besten spielem um menu implementiert

....

Comment: git push origin <your_branch_name>